# What are the relative advantages of XMLEncoder and XStream?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

Suppose I want to store many small configuration objects in XML, and I don't care too much about the format. The [XMLDecoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) class built into the JDK would work, and from what I hear, [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) works in a similar way.

What are the advantages to each library?

Answer (score 9):

I really like the [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
library. It does a really good job of outputting fairly simple xml
as a result of a provided Java object.  It works great for reproducing
the object back from the xml as well.  And, one of our 3rd party libraries
already depended on it anyway.

- We chose to use it because we wanted
  our xml to be human readable.  Using
  the alias function makes it much
  nicer.
- You can extend the library if you
  want some portion of an object to
  deserialize in a nicer fashion.  We
  did this in one case so the file
  would have a set of degrees,
  minutes, and seconds for a latitude
  and longitude, instead of two
  doubles.

The two minute tutorial sums up the basic usage, but in the 
interest of keeping the information in one spot, I'll try to sum it 
up here, just a little shorter.

```
// define your classes
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private PhoneNumber phone;
  // ... constructors and methods
}

public class PhoneNumber {
  private int code;
  private String number;
  // ... constructors and methods
}
```

Then use the library for write out the xml.

```
// initial the libray
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("person", Person.class); // elementName, Class
xstream.alias("phone", PhoneNumber.class); 

// make your objects
Person joe = new Person("Joe");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));

// convert xml
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

You output will look like this:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
</person>
```

To go back:

```
Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

The XMLEncoder is provided for Java bean serialization.  The last time I used it, 
the file looked fairly nasty. If really don't care what the file looks like, it could
work for you and you get to avoid a 3rd party dependency, which is also nice.  I'd expect the possibility of making the serialization prettier would be more a challenge with the XMLEncoder as well.

XStream outputs the full class name if you don't alias the name. If the Person class above had

```
package example;
```

the xml would have "example.Person" instead of just "person".

Comment: The "nasty" aspect of XMLEncoder ouput is mainly the fully qualified classnames. If I choose not to set up aliases, what does XStream do with package names? I have many types; class-specific code must be minimized. How would I write a generic XSLT to transform any XStreamed type to, say, JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd write an XSLT to go from XStream output to JSON?  You could ask a new question on SO. :)

Comment: That is the good part. JSON [already outputs to JSON](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Another suggestion: consider using JAXB (http://jaxb.dev.java.net). If you are using JDK 1.6, it comes bundled, check out "javax.xml.bind" for details, so no need for additional external jars.

JAXB is rather fast. I like XStream too, but it's bit slower. Also, XMLEncoder is bit of a toy (compared to other options)... but if it works, there's no harm in using it.

Also: one benefit of JAXB is that you can also bind partial document (sub-trees) with it; no need to create object(s) for the whole file. For this you need to use Stax (XMLStreamReader) to point to root element of the sub-tree, then bind. No need to use SAX, even for most large files, as long as it can be processed chunk by chunk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm making a distinction between binding and serialization, and this question is oriented at serialization. However, you mention that XMLEncoder is a toy compared to the others. Could you please cite some specific features of XStream that are lacking in XMLEncoder?

Comment: Fair enough. It's just that in most cases data-binding based serialization works just fine. And I didn't see anything indicating that JAXB wouldn't work.

Wrt toy: missing configurability, only writes beans (no field-based), xml integration (XE uses string concat, not xml writer), performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on storing all those configuration objects in a single file, and that file will be quite large, both the options you've outlined above could be quite memory intensive, as they both require the entire file to be read into memory to be deserialized.

If memory usage is a concern (the file containing the XML will be very large), I recommend [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/).

If memory usage is not a concern (the file containing the XML will not be very large), I'd use whatever is included with the default JRE (in this case XMLDecoder) just to remove 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: The whole point is, precisely, to load objects into memory. It's a deserialization mechanism. 

What I'd want to avoid is constructing a DOM, then walking it to produce a parallel object graph, because then I'd have *two* copies in memory, unnecessarily. XMLDecoder, at least, is SAX-based.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also prefer [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) as it is really easy to use and to extend. You can quickly start if you're going with the default setup. If you need to customize the behavior it has a very clean API and a lot of extension points, so you have really fine grained control over the things you want to tweak without interfering with other parts of the marshalling process.

As the XML that is created by XStream looks nice, manual editing is also simple. If the output doesn't fulfill your needs and the long list of available [Converters](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converters.html) doesn't contain the one you need, it's fairly simple to write your own.

A big plus is also the good documentation on their [homepage](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I always find XStream very tempting, because it's so easy to get going. However, invariably I end up replacing it. It's really quite buggy, and its collection handling could use a lot of work.

As a result, I usually switch to JAXB. It's an awful lot more robust, it's pretty much bug-free, and a more flexible than XStream.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @jay answer with example:

Code:

```
PortfolioAlternateIdentifier identifier = new PortfolioAlternateIdentifier();
identifier.setEffectiveDate(new Date());
identifier.setSchemeCode("AAA");
identifier.setIdentifier("123456");
```

**The output using XStream:**

```
<PortfolioAlternateIdentifier>
 <effectiveDate>2014-05-02 20:14:15.961 IST</effectiveDate>
 <schemeCode>AAA</schemeCode>
 <identifier>123456</identifier>
</PortfolioAlternateIdentifier>
```

**The output using XMLEncoder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <java version="1.6.0_38" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
   <object class="PortfolioAlternateIdentifier"> 
    <void property="effectiveDate"> 
  <object class="java.util.Date"> 
   <long>1399041855961</long> 
  </object> 
    </void> 
 <void property="identifier"> 
  <string>123456</string> 
 </void> 
   <void property="schemeCode"> 
    <string>AAA</string> 
   </void> 
  </object> 
</java>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java also has a new utility class aimed at storing Key-Value paired sets typical to configurations. It is the old style but very simple and handy. This is done via the [java.util.Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class, a Map object with serialization options. This might be all you need unless you are storing entire objects.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder like the plague if you're going to be persisting a non-trivial number of objects or your system needs to be multithreaded. See http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/do-not-want-xmlencoder-129.html for the grisly details.

If you must use XML, XStream is great. But ask yourself if you really need to use XML. Here's a serialization benchmark project that might turn you on to better solutions:

http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking