# alternative xml binding in java

Tags: java, xml, binding

What are you using for binding XML to Java? What are the better choice? I need speed in marshalling/unmarshalling. I have 20M xml-file. I need xml-to-java fastest framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java XML Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205749/java-xml-binding)

Comment: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/09/07/schema-less-java-xml-data-binding-with-vtd-xml.html

Comment: @vtd-xml-author - That article incorrectly states that JAXB and Castor require an XML schema.  They have the ability to generate an object model from an XML schema, but you can also start with objects and map them to XML without a schema.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB is the obvious choice. It's fairly simple, easy to understand, it's fast, and is built into Java6.

Comment: There are also multiple implementations of JAXB:  Metro (the reference implementation), EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc.

Comment: @Blaise: Indeed. However, bundling a 3rd-party one detracts somewhat from the convenience.

Comment: The ability to choose between implementations protects the developer from vendor lock in.  Also individual implementations offer extensions such as MOXy's XPath based mapping:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Answer (score 1):

XStream is really easy to use and I found it to be very fast:

http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Interesting, a very useful article there Blaise. I would certainly consider JAXB for future needs.  Do you have one covering the parsing side, as well as this output one?

Comment: The following articles demonstrates reading XML with JAXB: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll bear this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks that modify bytecode, like [jibx](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/), are probably the fastet solution. But they are not hassle free.
You will possibly need special plugins for you IDE that make the IDE understand what jibx does.

If speed is not the only factor, I'd go for XStream as Brian suggested. It is really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using JIBX for XML to java binding and I'm happy with it. It also has a maven plug-in so that you can give the binding configuration on build time in order not to face any problems at runtime. As to its speed, comes second one after JAXB.